# Using a constant in a PHP switch in PHP 5.5.9

Tags: php, switch-statement, php-5.5

After installing PHP 5.5.9 on [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr), I found this strange behavior with a `switch` statement and the `PHP_OS` constant.

I presume that in PHP 5.5.9 the switch statement is also checking for the same type (===)?

Or is it a PHP bug?

```
echo PHP_OS; // Linux
$os = PHP_OS;

switch (PHP_OS) {
    case "WINNT":
        echo 'Windows';
        break;
    case "Linux":
        echo 'Linux';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Default';
        break;
}
// Default

switch ((string) PHP_OS) {
    case "WINNT":
        echo 'Windows';
        break;
    case "Linux":
        echo 'Linux';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Default';
        break;
}
// Default

switch ($os) {
    case "WINNT":
        echo 'Windows';
        break;
    case "Linux":
        echo 'Linux';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Default';
        break;
}
// Linux
```

Comment: What's the "strange behavior"?

Comment: In previous versions of php `switch (PHP_OS)` would return "Selecting Linux"

Comment: @AsaCarter What happens if you replace `switch (PHP_OS)` with `switch ((string) PHP_OS)` ?

Comment: what's the content of PHP_OS now?

Comment: @ClémentMalet, I've updated the question with that code. Surprisingly it still does not work.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, the value of PHP_OS is Linux

Comment: I ran this code on PHP 5.5.9 with Ubuntu, I get the "Linux" output.

Comment: I tested it with PHP 5.5.15 and it works fine on Windows

Comment: My php version is PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3

Answer (score 2):

PHP switches use loose comparison like [`==`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), so it should match.

Try:

```
switch (constant("PHP_OS"))
```

Answer (score 0):

for those who want to have a solution for class constants we can use this method:

```
switch($var){
        case get_class_vars('CLASSNAME')['CONST_CLASS']:
break;
```