# PHP/CSS: My session variable is not loaded

Tags: php, css, variables

I'm trying to load parameters with php(stored in my database) to update my css.
After login, I start a session and load css in my header:

```
<head>      
<?PHP 
    define('THEME',  $_SESSION["theme"]);   
?>      
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./public_html/css/style.php" />
</head>
```

When I try to access test in style.php it doesn't work:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    switch(constant(THEME)){ something...}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I access my variable?

Comment: header only works if there hasn't been any output yet

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not sure I understand. So far I can access my variable in the header (I print to test...) but I can't access it in style.php. I don't know how to do to access it. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Place your `header(...)` ABOVE your `print` commands

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## New Answer

PHP Constants need to be generated when the page/script is generated and will only last for *that script* execution.

IF you want constants (As here) which last over multiple script/page loads of your website you need to use `$_SESSION` (or `$_COOKIE` ) values to carry the variable from page to page.

Thus:

As you set your constant here:

```
<?PHP 
    define('THEME',  $_SESSION["theme"]);   
?>
```

Using a `$_SESSION` value; simply ignore the constant in your `style.php` page and use the session variable.

Be sure to run `session_start();` at the [top of every script you want to read or write season data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27577693/3536236).

thus:

- style.php:

  ```
  <?php
      session_start(); //IMPORTANT! 
      header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
      switch($_SESSION["theme"]){ 
         case "a":
            ....
            break;
         case "b":
            ...
            etc.
         }
  ?>
  <html>
       ....
  ```

---

## Old Answer

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645533/using-a-constant-in-a-php-switch-in-php-5-5-9) you can do:

```
switch (constant("__TEST__")){
     case "Ok":
        print "this constant is ".__TEST__;
        break;

     ...
}
```

*Please also note that double underscore constants (`_ _ WORD _ _`) are generally reserved and using this style for custom constants is frowned upon.*

**Debug note:** 
Do NOT `print` any PHP output before your `header(...)` statement. The `header()` ***MUST*** come before anything is output to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the note, much appreciated. Anyway it still doesn't work. I can't access my session variable. I've got a header.html like this :  
    `<head>  
  <?PHP define('THEME',  $_SESSION['theme']); ?>  
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./public_html/css/style.php" />  
    </head>`

My style.php like this:  

    `header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");  
 switch(constant(THEME)){...something} `

Comment: You have not put `THEME` in quotes in your switch statement. @BenoitFrontzak

Comment: I tried. Now the warning message is:  Warning: constant(): Couldn't find constant THEME

Comment: @BenoitFrontzak please review my updated answer. This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the header function if you already have an output.
See the documentation : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php

You must set your header before anything else, like this :

```
 <?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    print $test; // prints KO
    print __TEST__; // prints KO
    switch(__TEST__){ something...}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Anyway it doesn't change anything. I still have the same issue. I can't access my variable...I don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you are also Missing an include or require Statement to get the $test variable into your style.php

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what to include, after login, I set  few session variables that I can access in all my pages but 'style.php'

Comment: Die you started the Session in your style.php ?